# Decimal to binary converter loop issue

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm having an issue with my decimal to binary converter. I'm using String to get a number and then I run the loop to look for '1'. It does the job but prints too many zeros at the end. Any ideas what should I look for to get rid of the excessive 0's?

```
System.out.print("Please enter Decimal number: ");
    int decimalNum = kybd.nextInt();

    power = 0;
    expo = 2;
    sum = 0;
    String finalNumber = "";

    for (int i = decimalNum; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        if(decimalNum%2 != 0)
        {
            finalNumber += '1'; 
        }
        else
            finalNumber += '0';


    decimalNum = decimalNum/2;

    }//end of decimalLoop

    for(int i = finalNumber.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(finalNumber.charAt(i)== '1')
        {
            //finalNumber = finalNumber + finalNumber.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(finalNumber.charAt(i));
        }
        else
            //finalNumber = finalNumber + finalNumber.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(finalNumber.charAt(i));
    }
```

Please enter Decimal number: 10

0000001010

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are converting from decimal to binary in the question you provided.

There is a lot of unnecessary code. You should remove extra variables. Also I dont see the point of if-else in the final loop. The actual bug lies in the first for loop. It can be converted into a while loop instead of the logic which you used of decrementing by one and diving by 2. What you are doing is assigning `i = decimalNum` then dividing `decimalNum/2` and reducing i by 1 `i--`. So for 10, i will be 10,4,1 instead of 10,5,2,1

```
String finalNumber = "";
    while (decimalNum > 0) {
        if(decimalNum%2 != 0)
            finalNumber += '1'; 
        else
            finalNumber += '0';
        decimalNum = decimalNum/2;
    }//end of decimalLoop
    for(int i = finalNumber.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
        System.out.print(finalNumber.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did remove my final if loop and replaced it with yours but I'm still getting two many zeros. Any reason why?
Please enter Decimal number: 10
0000001010

Comment: @user2888585 did you change your first for loop?

Comment: how would it be if I want to use for-loop?

Comment: if you want to use for-loop it should be for(;decimalNum>0;decimalNum/=2)

Comment: hrv, I don't understand your last answer. Can you put it into the for-loop syntax? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I highly recommend you reading about [for loops here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). The for loop syntax is right in front of you in the comments :)

Comment: I did correct my for-loop to :
for (int i = decimalNum; i > 0; i--)
I don't see any errors, it should drop after 1/2 and do not execute more to the string. i.e we are at the last loop where decimalNum = 1. 1/2 =0 so for loop should stop. I'm having additional 6 zeros and I don't know why.

Comment: got it my self. the i in the for-loop was the problem. since it was still looping with larger numbers. another if in the loop with break did the trick:
for (int i = decimalNum; i > 0; i--)
  {
   if(decimalNum%2 != 0)
   {
    finalNumber += '1'; 
   }
   else
    finalNumber += '0';
   
  decimalNum = decimalNum/2;
  
  if(decimalNum == 0)
   break;

Comment: Glad you figured it out yourself. Also you can make the code much simpler by removing the variable i